# Silverlight UI Thread Blocking

Tags: silverlight

Can someone please tell me how the processing in Silverlight processes between the UI Thread and the other "worker" threads.

I have a scenario where I have to update several hundred complex UI objects in the view via a viewmodel. Each item is backed by its own viewmodel.

If each viewmodel had a property, for example, called IsSelected, which changed a background color through behaviours, how should I go about making changes to minimal UI Thread blocking?

If I update my (several hundred) viewmodels, it blocks the UI thread for around 4 seconds. How can I determine what's doing the blocking? Are there more efficient ways to update?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are definitely more efficient ways than doing it in one go.

A non-Silverlight specific solution would be to space these updates a few milliseconds apart with DispatcherTimer delayed calls, so the thread has some "breathing space" to carry on with the execution path.

But you should also give some thought to your architecture, if you're dealing with hundreds of VMs it might worth using lazy loading and updating your screen sequentially, in order of importance for your audience.

See this answer too for more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710868/21217